# Generating more MYSQL database results when a dropdown list is selected

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

hope you can help

I want to have a drop down list that searches my mysql database and shows the first and last names of the users. You can then select any of the names and it will generate the rest of the membership details (i.e. date signed up, last logged in etc).

I have got the dropdown list working fine, but my problem comes with the next step of generating the rest of the details. With my below code it just shows the details of the last user who signed up and does not change when I change the name in the drop down menu.

I'm pretty sure I need Javascript to help get this working but as I am a beginner to PHP/MYSQL any advise toward the right direction for me would be great. Thanks

This is the code which searches my database and puts the first and last name in to a drop down list

```
$sql = "SELECT first_name,last_name FROM registration_tbl";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
echo '<select name="name" style="width: 400px">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $firstname = $row['first_name'];
    $lastname = $row['last_name'];
    echo'<option>' . $firstname . " " . $lastname . '</option>';
}
echo '</select> <p>';
```

Again the above code works fine, but the below code is what I am having difficulty with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registration_tbl WHERE first_name = '".$firstname."'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "ID: " . " " . $row[0] . "<br>" . 
        "Name: " . $row[1] . " " . $row[2] . "<br>" . 
        "Company: " . $row[3] . "<br> " . 
        "Email: " .$row[4] . "<br> " . 
        "Date of registration: " . $row[6] . "<br> " . 
        "Last login:  " .$row[7] . "<br>" . 
        "Admin/User: " .$row[8] . "<p>";
}
```

Comment: If you want to display the details in the same page you'll need AJAX, if you want to display the details doing a full page load you won't need javascript at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "having difficulty"? What happens when this code is executed? Does it display anything? If not, maybe the ```$firstname``` does not exists in the table?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. Yes I am wanting them to load onto the same page. I shall have a look around AJAX and see what I can find. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @mTorres - in regards to your second comment. Yes it works to the extent that it is retrieving the information from the database and is showing them correctly, but it is just the information from the last person who registered, I want to be able to select any of the names from the drop down menu and for this to change to their relevant details, which it does not. It does not change, just stays the same.

Comment: If you're new the PHP for AJAX things my advice is that you check [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and also have some read on [separation of concerns](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html), though in the symfony documentation this document shows why the separation of concerns - buissnes logic & presentation mainly - are important and how to achieve it (you can achieve it without using a framework :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to use AJAX to dynamically load the content, you need a form to submit the data, your problem is that after your first loop, $firstname is the last user loaded into the , to make your code work, you need a form.

just put the select in a form and add a button

```
    <form action="mypage.php" method="get">
    <select name="name" style="width: 400px">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT first_name,last_name FROM registration_tbl";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $firstname = $row['first_name'];
        $lastname = $row['last_name'];
        echo'<option>' . $firstname . " " . $lastname . '</option>';
    }
    ?>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="Load User Data">
</form>
```

then in mypage.php you need to check if the form is submitted, and show the user details.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["name"]))  {
   //this form is posted, show user details
   //$firstname = $_GET["name"]; <--- SQL Injection enabled here!!
   $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["name"]); // please try to avoid SQL injection!
   //your code continues here
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM registration_tbl WHERE first_name = '".$firstname."'";
   $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      echo "ID: " . " " . $row[0] . "<br>" . 
        "Name: " . $row[1] . " " . $row[2] . "<br>" . 
        "Company: " . $row[3] . "<br> " . 
        "Email: " .$row[4] . "<br> " . 
        "Date of registration: " . $row[6] . "<br> " . 
        "Last login:  " .$row[7] . "<br>" . 
        "Admin/User: " .$row[8] . "<p>";
   }
```

}

last note, if you don't want the username to appear in the querystring, change form action to post, and get variable using $_POST["name"]

EDIT: if you want the form to autopost using javascript then add this to ur select definition:

```
<select name="name" style="width: 400px" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

but bear in mind that a lot of users block javascript, thus this will not work.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys, I wanted to look in to dandoonian's response first to see how I got on & will then take a look at AJAx and the other responses I've had.

@dandoonian - I did what you said in your example the dropdown and button work but now the second query to retrieve the other information doesn't show anything. I have tried putting this on a seperate php file and on the same one to see if it made a difference but it's not showing anything other than the dropdown and the button. any ideas?

Comment: try to echo $firstname to see it's returning a value, and ofcourse make sure that your opening the connection to ur database in the second page. one last note, if your html select is named: myselection <select name="myselection"> then you should get the firstname via $_GET["myselection"]

Comment: The $firstname echos out the first name of the last user who signed up (I see where this is going) - Yeah the Database is open and connecting okay - I had been thinking that it was where i was getting the firstname from which was the problem and this looks to be true. Athough this doesn't seem to be working;     "SELECT * FROM registration_tbl WHERE first_name = '".$_GET["name"]."'"; by not working I mean it isn't showing any extra information

Comment: EDIT: Ignore what I just said ^^ It's working now - I needed the firstname via $GET etc that is where my problems had been lying. Thank you for your help. I'm glad I have a sure fire way of getting it to work - I'm still going to look in to JQUERY/AJAX to expand my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use AJAX to get the data of the other script. However, another (far less elegant and efficient) way of doing it is while you're looping through the names to put into the select. You can also be using the names to get the info for that name and put it into an array (but don't echo it) until you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code from where user will select the name

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

$(".listdata").change(function()
{
var dataString = 'listdata='+ $(this).val();
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "alldata",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".alldata").html(html);
} 
});

});
});
</script>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT first_name,last_name FROM registration_tbl";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
echo '<select name="name" style="width: 400px" class="listdata">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $firstname = $row['first_name'];
    $lastname = $row['last_name'];
    echo'<option value="'.$firstname.'">' . $firstname . " " . $lastname . '</option>';
}
echo '</select> <p>';
?>
<div class="alldata">
    <!--here your all data will come-->

</div>
<br/><br/>
```

Crate one more and give the name alldata.php
And use the below code on that page

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registration_tbl WHERE first_name = '".$firstname."'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "ID: " . " " . $row[0] . "<br>" . 
        "Name: " . $row[1] . " " . $row[2] . "<br>" . 
        "Company: " . $row[3] . "<br> " . 
        "Email: " .$row[4] . "<br> " . 
        "Date of registration: " . $row[6] . "<br> " . 
        "Last login:  " .$row[7] . "<br>" . 
        "Admin/User: " .$row[8] . "<p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I was using jQuery 1.4 you can use latest version but the main think is work should be done

Comment: Hi @Jha - Thanks for the reply. I decided to copy what you had done and then if it worked I would go off and learn more about it so I can understand it and how it works. 

The problem I have at the moment is that if I put the 2nd lot of code onto a new file called alldata.php it shows the names in the drop down menu but that is it. And if I paste it at the bottom of the same file as the top code example you gave it shows the drop down ok but still only shows the extra information of the last user who signed up.

Comment: See i have given the url of alldata.php so if you want to do in the same page then you need to change the url and if($_POST['listdata'])
{ Write here alldat.php code then it will work}

Comment: I have changed url: "alldata",to url: "testajax", and underneath the <br> of the first block of code I put if($_POST['listdata']){ } and pasted the second lot of code in it. But still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete your options, here you have a **full but basic AJAX implementation** (using jQuery):

File **select.php** (javascript part at the bottom of the file):

```
<?php
  // Notice that you'll need to get the $dbc from somewhere, maybe require 'db.php'?
  // Retrieve list of people... (notice I've added id column!)
  $sql = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM registration_tbl";
  $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
  $people = [];
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $people[$row['id']] = $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>List of people</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .error {
        color: red;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(247, 17, 40, 0.44);
    }
    #person-info {
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>People list</h2>
    <label for="person">Please select one person</label> 
    <select name="person" id="people-selection">
        <option value="-1"></option>

    <?php foreach ($people as $person_id => $person_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $person_id ?>"><?php echo $person_name ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>
  <div id="person-info"><!-- here we will put person info using AJAX request --></div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // We bind our AJAX handler to the onChange event of the select element
        $("#people-selection").on('change', function(e) {
            if ($(this).val() != -1) {  // If we did select some value
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "/get_people_info.php",
                    data: { id: $(this).val() },
                })
                  .done(function(data) {
                    $("#person-info")
                        .removeClass("error")  // we don't need the error class here, it's a success response
                        .html(data);
                  })
                  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#person-info")
                        .addClass("error")      // in order to add some UI for the user
                        .html("Something went wrong!<br><blockquote>" + errorThrown + "</blockquote>");
                  });
            }
            else {
                $("#person-info")
                    .removeClass("error")
                    .html("");
            }
        })
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then **get_people_info.php**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== "POST") {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request');
    die("Only POST request accedpted!");
}

if (!isset($_POST['id'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request');
    die("id parameter is mandatory!");
}

$id = (int) $_POST['id'];

// Notice that you'll need to get the $dbc from somewhere, maybe require 'db.php'?
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registration_tbl WHERE id = ". $id .";";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<p>ID: " . " " . $row[0] . "<br>" . 
         "Name: " . $row[1] . " " . $row[2] . "<br>" . 
         "Company: " . $row[3] . "<br> " . 
         "Email: " .$row[4] . "<br> " . 
         "Date of registration: " . $row[6] . "<br> " . 
         "Last login:  " .$row[7] . "<br>" . 
         "Admin/User: "  .$row[8] . "</p>";
}
else {
    echo "Person not found!";
}
```

Let me give you some further reading (you said you were new to PHP, I asume the whole web development):

- [jQuery Learning center](http://learn.jquery.com/)
- [PHP: The right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Comment: Thanks @mTorres - I have changed the 'id's to 'user_ID' as this is what my field is called on my database, but I can't seem to understand why it isn't working. The drop downlist generates okay but when I select a name I get the red box with "something went wrong Not found" error in it.

Comment: can you try to put in your browser the *get_people_info.php*, you should recieve an error stating that only POST requests allowed, but my guess is that the AJAX call is not hitting your PHP script, so check the names of the PHP script and the *url* parameter on the ```$.ajax``` call in the JS code